# Once per all: How to deploy an application using Oracle.DataAccess in Any Cpu mode?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

My application uses Oracle as database. 
How can I compile it using Any Cpu Platform and run it on x86 and x64 servers regardless the oracle client installed there?
If you can point me versions and download links (Ex: Oracle.DataAccess.Dll) I would really appreciate.

Cheers,

André

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trying to not need two separate solutions for x86 and x64 program.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599797/trying-to-not-need-two-separate-solutions-for-x86-and-x64-program)

Comment: Not the same. Sean already have two solutions and he wants to know how to handle that. I definitely don't want 2 solutions and I want to know about the oracle client installed on target machines as well.