# AnyCPu vs ODP.NET

Tags: c#, oracle, x86, 64-bit, anycpu

My config: Vs2015  /  X64 PC  /  ODP.NET X86

I've wrote a few DLL on 'Any Cpu' mode and I would like to write programs that use this DLLs and that can be work on X64 and X86 machins.

But I referenced "Oracle.DataAccess.dll" in my Dlls then I've a warning 'ProcessorArchitecture=X86' on Oracle DLL.

How can I do (I can install ODP.NET X64 if necessary) ?

thks

Comment: Try compiling for X86.  A X64 should be able to read an X86, but an X86 cannot read an X64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you compile your DLL with "x86" then also the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` **must** be the x86 version (i.e. 32 bit version)

When you compile your DLL with "x64" then also the `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` **must** be the x64 version (i.e. 64 bit version)

For "AnyCPU" it depends, there is no "AnyCPU" version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. If your application runs on 64-bit Windows it will run as x64 process - thus also `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` must be the x64 version. If your application runs on 32-bit Windows it will run as x86 process - thus also `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` must be the x86 version.

To cut a long story short: architecture of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` must be the same as the application, i.e. your DLL.

Follow this instruction to run both in parallel: 
[BadImageFormatException. This will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104210/badimageformatexception-this-will-occur-when-running-in-64-bit-mode-with-the-32#24120100)

**Update**

In your `*.csproj`, resp. `*.vbproj` edit your reference to ODP.NET like this:

```
<Reference Include="Oracle.DataAccess">
  <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
  <Private>False</Private>
</Reference>
```

Attributes like `Version=...` or `processorArchitecture=...` are not required. Your application will load the correct `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` depending on selected architecture and target .NET framework (provided that it is installed properly)

Comment: On my devlopment PC, in VS2015, I must add Oracle DLL on project references. Then I must choose an Oracle DLL. Then I must choose between x86 or X64 DLL no ?

Comment: I follow instruction to install X86 and X64 Oracle Client. It seems good. I've added Oracle.DataAccess reference in my project and modifiy '.csproj'. when I compile in X86 or X64 it's ok but if I use 'Any CPU' I've warning => 'There is a difference between the processor architecture of the "MSIL" generation project and the reference processor architecture "Oracle.DataAccess", "AMD64". This difference can cause runtime problems...'

Comment: "AnyCPU" is a problem because there is no "AnyCPU" version of `Oracle.DataAccess.dll`. Without knowing the customer Windows version (32/64-bit) you cannot determine. In my application I compile two versions at the same time: `<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU'" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Platform=x64;PlatFormTarget=x64" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />
    <MSBuild Condition="'$(Platform)' == 'AnyCPU'" Projects="$(MSBuildProjectFile)" Properties="Platform=x86;PlatFormTarget=x86" RunEachTargetSeparately="true" />
</Target>
`

Comment: Finally I decided to work in X64 (since "AnuCpu" can not work with Oracle).
Unfortunately I just realized that I can not use UserControls compiled in X64 in visual studio (these UserControls referencing the Oracle DLL).This means that in my case I have to stay in X86?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to target x86 - a 64-bit operating system can still load and run 32-bit applications, and so this would mean your app can run on both x86 and x64 machines.

The downside is that your app **must** run as a 32-bit processes, i.e. your process will have a 4GB maximum address space and cannot load 64-bit assemblies. If you try to load your dll in a 64-bit process (e.g. because IIS hasn't been configured to use a 32-bit app pool) you will get a `BadImageFormatException`.

If thats not acceptable to you then you could try detecting the process version and dynamically loading the correct assembly [as per this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16831272/113141)

Answer (score 0):

All the above mentioned solutions are correct, but I just feel the need to mention Oracle.ManagedDataAcces as it does not care what the bitness is.